# Hitting SSL Rest end point using SoapUI works, but not using postman

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, soapui, postman

I'm trying to create a SSL rest endpoint (just a hello world get request) using spring boot.

I created a self signed certificate and imported into the PKCS12 keystore using the following command, and was able to successfully add it to the keystore of Tomcat embedded within spring boot application.
I was using postman to test my endpoint. Before that, I successfully imported the client certificate as described in the link - http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/ to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and also in personal.

In spite of importing the client certificate, the request through postman fails. However, if I try to hit the same HTTPS endpoint using SoapUI, I get a successful response.

Note: In the link - http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/ someone had already raised a similar issue. However, not sure whether this was addressed by postman.

Any help on this is much appreciated!!!

**Command used to create used to create keystore:**

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore "c:\cert\keystore.p12" -validity 3650
```

**spring boot application.properties:**

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```